# submit button in JSP does not trigger doPost in Servlet

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, servlets, post

I have a form that lives in a .jsp file (yarntree.jsp). The form is populated when a user clicks on a google map, via a javascript function that lives in an external js file (map.java). I want to send that data to an sql database, and then have the original jsp page redisplay with the form now empty. The code for that lives in a .java file (YarnTreeServlet.java). The mappings are in web.xml

I am using V3 of the maps api, along with appengine.

Web app can be seen here:

Problem: the submit button does not result in anything being sent to the doPost method.

I have added some code in the javascript to write out the values to the console and those are populated correctly. I have checked the query, and it would insert correctly if doPost worked. I have spent hours on this, and am at loss. Is there some reason why I cannot access the values that are in the form once they have populated? I am aware that the servlet mapping is likely part of the problem, but I have tried a number of variations with no success. At this point I am unable to tell if the problem is in the js, the jsp, the form, the doPost, or the web.xml. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I can't see the servlet url in `<form>` tag.

```
  <form id="createMarkerForm" 
        method="post" 
        accept-charset="utf-8" 
        action="servletUrl">
```

and doPost is not override properly.

```
 @Override
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, 
                    HttpServletResponse resp) 
                        throws ServletException, IOException{    
 }
```

Comment: @Franky Hi, thanks for replying so fast. I have 2 questions about your response: what do you mean is not overridden properly? Should it not say @Override? Or should there be a whole different version of the method be there?  The form action is something that confuses me - is the servlet url the same as the name of the .java file that has the doPost? Also I included the web.xml file, in the hopes that if it were the mappings, some one could help me figure out what was supposed to go where.

Comment: I suggest a good tutorial about servlets and their mapping, it could be quite useful! Good luck.

Comment: I've been through a few of them - but none explain how the form action ties into the web.xml or how the form ties into the Servlet - i.e. the redirect and the forward. Believe me, the last thing I wanted to do was demonstrate my ignorance on a site I revere, but I am truly stuck in a circular set of change and hope since I have of how the three should be set. Still, thanks for trying.

Comment: @user1545253 - You need to set `<form action="new" ...>` attribute. Did you tried that?

Comment: In the form, I have set form action="new". I also double checked and my doPost method actually has the @Override tag, I just missed it in the cut and paste. I will edit the original code to reflect the current state. I also included the web.xml bits for that servlet. Also, many thanks!

Comment: Am I misunderstanding how the values come back from the javascript? I should be able to read them once the form populates, correct?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that I needed to do 'doGet' and not doPost. From what I understand, this is because I am needing the value of the parameters that are being processed via jquery as a result of a onclick even in javascript.

Thank you for all your help.